# Podspec validation error - unknown error

Tags: git, cocoapods

I encountered an unknown error when use  'pod spec lint CDNKit.podspec' command

> -> CDNKit (0.0.1)
>
> ```
> - WARN  | source: The version should be included in the Git tag.
>
> - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Must be in the root of the repo (/Users/iOS/.cocoapods/repos/master), instead in
>  /Users/iOS/Desktop/cdn/CDNKit.) during validation.
>   Analyzed 1 podspec.
> ```
>
> [!] The spec did not pass validation, due to 1 error and 1 warning.

How could I solve it?

Comment: It would be good if you could show your podspec(in case you can) so we can help you.

Comment: Thank you for your reply. But there is nothing special in the podspec, only some configurations such as  `s.name = "CDNKit"   s.version      = "0.0.1"
  s.license  = "MIT"` etc.